# list doesn't contain its own members in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list containing one member, that member is the string `<cmd_stichstudy1>XXDDR0_MA[12]`. When I search for that string in the list (using `lsearch`) I get that the list doesn't contain it. I even get it when I search for the member of the list:

```
tcl> set nets_names

{<cmd_stichstudy1>XXDDR0_MA[12]}

tcl> lsearch $nets_names [lindex $nets_names 0]

-1
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Just to expand on the correct answers, because the search string contains square brackets, with glob-style matching, `lsearch` is trying to match either `<cmd_stichstudy1>XXDDR0_MA1` or `<cmd_stichstudy1>XXDDR0_MA2` -- documented on the [`string match` man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [-exact](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lsearch.htm#M6) it will work the way you want.

```
% set nets_names {<cmd_stichstudy1>XXDDR0_MA[12]}
<cmd_stichstudy1>XXDDR0_MA[12]
% lsearch -exact $nets_names [lindex $nets_names 0]
0
%
```

Answer (score 2):

`lsearch` has an unfortunate property of using [glob-style matching](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40) by default.

To cite the manual:

> If all matching style options are omitted, the default matching style is -glob.

So always pass `-exact` to `lsearch` unless you really want `-glob`.